# Practice webdriver , need application

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I need an application to practice selenium webdriver. Can anyone suggest me some applications which i can work even offline.

Note: Please don't refer Actitime. there is some issue installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **offline** try

https://github.com/eviltester/seleniumtestpages

For **online**

http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/

http://www.way2automation.com/demo.html

Hope this helps you..